# Text to complete the analogy? Calculus:Real Analysis::Intro Stats:??

Tags: statistics, reference-request

The subject pretty says it all, but I am hoping to find a text that rigorously does statistics like, say, Rudin does for Real Analysis.  (Having mentioned Rudin, I'm not really looking for a text that leaves so much to the exercises.)  At a bare minimum, I'd like to find a text that can state and prove the Central Limit Theorem.

Thanks!

Comment: Pretty much any advanced undergraduate level statistics book, such as Hogg/McKean/Craig's [**Introduction to Mathematical Statistics**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0321795431).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your analogy of Calculus->Real Analysis goes so far as to include measure theory (i.e. not something that I saw in my first or second real analysis course, but which did show up in my first graduate course in real analysis) then you might look at [A Probability Path](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817684085) by Sidney Resnick.  It builds probability theory from a rigorous (real analysis + measure theory) background--it doesn't assume you've previously had a course in measure theory, but it would help.  It covers "classic" things (with proof) such as: the law of large numbers and the central limit theorem.

If you are looking for a more general field (than a specific textbook), then you probably want to look into (rigorous) probability theory.  A good textbook in this field will look a lot like a real analysis textbook (but it is all applied to probability and statistics).